# internal link defined in javascript not working with htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a javascript captcha running on a website that works with a direct link; so, the captcha works with the link format below:

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=page&option1=1&option2=2
```

However, if I use the htaccess - seo optimized link below, the javascript doesn't seem to find the predefined directory within the javascript.

```
http://example.com/1/2
```

My htaccess file redirects as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /dir/index.php?p=page&option1=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /dir/index.php?p=page&option1=$1&option2=$2    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /dir/index.php?p=page&option1=&option2=$2&option3=&option4=&option5=$1&option6=$3    [NC,L]
```

I have tried multiple variations of the javascript defined urls (captchaDir: and url:) The javascript that predefines the location of the directory looks like this:

```
var defaults = {  
   borderColor: "",  
   captchaDir: "replyform/captcha",  
   url: "replyform/captcha/captcha.php",  
   formId: "myForm",  
   text: "Verify that you are a human,<br />drag <span>scissors</span> into the circle.",
   items: Array("pencil", "scissors", "clock", "heart", "note") 
  };
```

the directory layout is like this: the index.php & .htaccess file is in:

```
/home/user/public_html/dir/
```

the captcha script is in:

```
/home/user/public_html/dir/replyform/captcha
```

Issue is that it works great with the regular php url, but does not work with the seo-friendly htaccess induced url.